# Defining arbitrary length bit-string literals for constant std_ulogic_vector in VHDL

Tags: digital-logic, vhdl, programmable-logic

I want to be able to define a simple **constant** for *DEFAULT_BUS* as all **Z**, or some other *std_ulogic* value, but its length should depend upon another **generic** value as per instantiation and it'd be nice to instantiate that default as per the designer's whim, so;

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity foo is
    generic (
        BUS_WIDTH         : positive   :=  8; -- TYPICALLY 8-bits WIDE
        BUS_DEFAULT_LOGIC : std_ulogic := 'Z' -- DEFAULT BUS VALUE WHEN foo IS bar
    );

    type bus_type is std_ulogic_vector(BUS_WIDTH-1 downto 0);

    constant DEFAULT_BUS : bus_type := B" **ALWAYS_ALL_SOMETHINGS_HOWEVER_MANY_SOMETHINGS** ";

...
end entity foo;
```

Being new to VHDL and used to VERILOG, I'm aware I am missing something simple but I haven't had my coffee yet this morning.

As an aside, in VERILOG it would simply be; `BUS_WIDTH{BUS_DEFAULT_LOGIC};`

Does VHDL have an equivalent?

Comment: The syntax of type declaration precludes defining a type from another type. You could use a subtype declaration or simply an array constraint in the subtype indication of the object declaration: `constant DEFAULT_BUS: std_ulogic_vector (BUS_WIDTH - 1 downto 0) := (others => BUS_DEFAULT_LOGIC);`. Where the right hand side aggregate uses named association, required by a need to distinguish between an expression of the generic constant of type std_ulogic in parentheses and an aggregate. Your terse code displays no need for a type declaration which could require type conversion to use.

Comment: There are other issues. Type std_ulogic_vector is not a resolved type, meaning multiple drivers are not allowed. This would preclude usefulness of some of the meta values for enumerated element type std_ulogic in some cases ('Z', 'W', 'L'). ... is not a lexical element in VHDL nor is .. . There is not valid syntax containing three consectutive periods. A type declaration would look like `type bus_type is array (BUS_WIDTH - 1 downto 0) of std_ulogic;`. A subtype declaration `subtype bus_type is std_ulogic_vector (BUS_WIDTH - 1 downto 0);`.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect the answer is;

```
constant DEFAULT_BUS : bus_type := (others => BUS_DEFAULT_LOGIC);
```

Comment: The arrow goes `=>`, other than that, yes